# What does "Modify files with subversion/git" mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svn, git

```
% rails
...
General Options:
...
-c, --svn                        Modify files with subversion. (Note: svn must be in path)
-g, --git                        Modify files with git. (Note: git must be in path)
```

What do these "Modify files" options do for me?

Edit: It is unclear to me what using one (or both?) of these options actually does. As in, how do they alter workflow? What svn/git commands would I then not be issuing myself, or possibly what type of more esoteric commands will I now end up having to issue? Fundamentally, where are the docs on this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `--git` was added in [r8772](http://dev.rubyonrails.org/changeset/8772) in response to [ticket #10690](http://dev.rubyonrails.org/ticket/10690).  Reading that patch is the closest thing to documentation I've found.  The option applies to [Rails::Generator::Commands](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Generator/Commands.html), and does the appropriate `svn add` or `git add` for files created by `script/generate`.

It also does the appropriate `rm` or `reset` for things removed by `script/destroy`.

It does *not* commit any changes, only adds the files so they're tracked by the VCS.

Oh, and `--git` is also [broken for the rails app generator](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/3896-generatorcommandscreatefile-git-broken-with-app-generator), at least through rails 2.3.5.

Answer (score 1):

'-c' will direct rails to retrieve and store data from a subversion source code repositry.
'-g' will drect reails to retrieve and store code in a git repository.

In both cases the source code repositry must be installed and configured, and, you should have previously set your local environment to point to the desired  instance , project directories etc.

Comment: You didn't answer OP's questions of "How do they alter workflow? What svn/git commands would I then not be issuing myself?"

Answer (score 0):

Many dewelopers use a version control system to manage their projects. For Rails apps Subversion and Git are the most popular choices, Git tending to take over these days.

These systems help teams of developers collaborate by editing files without 'stepping on each other's toes'. That is to say if 2 collaborators edit 2 different parts of the same file at the same time, both edits will safely saved.

Even solo programmers find that using svn and git brings lots of advantages.

If you modify o file, renaming it or otherwise, you need to then commit these changes to the repository. The command above saves one step by commiting the changes to the repository on top of changing the file itself.

You need to look for info about the basics of Subversion and Git. One way is to go to [Github.com](http://github.com).

Comment: The question was about a flag to `rails`, not about the VCS themselves.